# Binary Tree - Array Implementation Basics [Homework]

Tags: arrays, binary-tree

**The Background:** "Using the tree below, give the array index for each element." It's a really simple problem, as my class just started going over it--but I require clarification on a small aspect.

**The Tree:**

```
                [A]
            /        \
         [B]         [D]
            \      /     \
            [E]   [F]    [G]
           /   \
         [H]    [I]
```

**My Question:** This is pretty much how my teacher drew it. Notice how child E is on the RIGHT side of parent B. Usually, to add the left child of a node you do 2(n)+1; Then for the right child of the node it's 2(n)+2. So my question is pretty straight forward.. is E's location in the array 2(1)+1 since it's the *only* child OR is it 2(1)+2 because it's drawn on the *right* side.

**Note:** I'm not asking for the whole assignment, just this one discrepancy. Everything else is taken care of. (Everything after E can be changed if my assumption is wrong or remain the same if I assumed correctly)

Comment: If the letters were put in the tree in alphabetical order, then the tree would contain 1) A.  2) A B.  B was the only child and it went on the left. Therefore only-childs go on the left. That removes one of your options.

Comment: I don't really think there was a specific order. The tree was just a diagram on a word document; basically as a picture. Also, there was no C--just extra info.

Comment: I re-read your comment and just understood it. Thank you.